# Any way to write " *:nth-child(2) " in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to hide the second child of a div (`#parentDiv`) irrespective of the html-tag `p`, `h2`, `h3` or `div`.

I could write all possible combinations in CSS, but it seemed to be clumsy as the html-tag of the element here can vary and is unpredictable. So I suppose writing up all HTML-tags is not a good approach.

Hence I tried below generalized approach in CSS, but did not work.

```
#parentDiv *:nth-child(2) {
   display: none;
}
```

I do not need a JavaScript solution.

Comment: Looks like it works to me... https://jsfiddle.net/x6a6jg3n/

Comment: Opps my bad. :P  missed out a brace :P

Comment: visibility: hidden;   use this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks good and fine.. Check for brackets. You may have forgot to close brackets.

Comment: Speak English. Stack Overflow is not an Indian site.

Comment: Okay. Will do sir. and @Nidhin S G life saver.